# How to tackle creating complex form with lots of custom components?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Let's say that my generated html from angular2 app looks like this:

```
<app>
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
<panel-component>
    <mid-component>
        <inner-component-with-inputs>
            <input/>
        <inner-component-with-inputs>
    <mid-component>
</panel-component>
<panel-component>
    <mid-component>
        <inner-component-with-inputs>
            <input/>
        <inner-component-with-inputs>
    <mid-component>
</panel-component>

<!-- many many many fields -->

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</app>
```

How can I set up my outer `<form>` in such a way that I can validate all inner inputs on submit? Do I have to pass `myForm` through `@Input()` all the way down from `panel-component` to `inner-component-with-inputs`? Or is there other way?

In my application I have very big form with multiple panels, subpanels, tabs, modals etc. and I need to be able to validate it all at once on submit.

All the tutorials and resources on the internet talk only about forms spanning one component/template.

Comment: In case you're still looking for an answer, I found that this helped me, particularly the plunker found in kara's comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9281#issuecomment-238610807

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A common pattern you will see throughout the Angular source code, when parent/child relationships are involved, is the parent type adding itself as a provider to itself. What this does is allow child component to inject the parent. And there will on only be one instance of the parent component all the way *down* the component tree because of [hierarchical DI](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html). Below is an example of what that might look like

```
export abstract class FormControlContainer {
  abstract addControl(name: string, control: FormControl): void;
  abstract removeControl(name: string): void;
}

export const formGroupContainerProvider: any = {
  provide: FormControlContainer,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => NestedFormComponentsComponent)
};

@Component({
  selector: 'nested-form-components',
  template: `
    ...
  `,
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, ChildComponent],
  providers: [formGroupContainerProvider]
})
export class ParentComponent implements FormControlContainer {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  addControl(name: string, control: FormControl) {
    this.form.addControl(name, control);
  }

  removeControl(name: string) {
    this.form.removeControl(name);
  }
}
```

Some notes:

- We're using an interface/abstract parent (`FormControlContainer`) for a couple reasons

  1. It decouples the `ParentComponent` from the `ChildComponent`. The child doesn't need to know anything about the specific `ParentComponent`. All it knows about is the `FormControlContainer` and the contract that is has.
  2. We only expose methods on the `ParentComponent` that want, through the interface contract.
- We only *advertise* `ParentComponent` as `FormControlContainer`, so the latter is what we will inject.
- We create a provider in the form of the `formControlContainerProvider` and then add that provider to the `ParentComponent`. Because of hierarchical DI, now all the children have access to the parent.
- If you are unfamiliar with `forwardRef`, [this is a great article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html)

Now in the child(ren) you can just do

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    ...
  `,
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnDestroy {
  firstName: FormControl;
  lastName: FormControl;

  constructor(private _parent: FormControlContainer) {
    this.firstName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.lastName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this._parent.addControl('firstName', this.firstName);
    this._parent.addControl('lastName', this.lastName);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._parent.removeControl('firstName');
    this._parent.removeControl('lastName');
  }
}
```

IMO, this is a much better design than passing the `FormGroup` through `@Input`s. As stated earlier, this is a common design throughout the Angular source, so I think it's safe to say that it's an acceptable pattern.

If you wanted to make the child components more reusable, you could make the constructor parameter `@Optional()`.

Below is the complete source I used to test the above examples

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, ViewChildren, QueryList, OnDestroy, forwardRef, Injector
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ControlContainer,
  Validators,
  FormGroupDirective,
  REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES
} from '@angular/forms';


export abstract class FormControlContainer {
  abstract addControl(name: string, control: FormControl): void;
  abstract removeControl(name: string): void;
}

export const formGroupContainerProvider: any = {
  provide: FormControlContainer,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => NestedFormComponentsComponent)
};

@Component({
  selector: 'nested-form-components',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <child-component></child-component>
      <div>
        <button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, forwardRef(() => ChildComponent)],
  providers: [formGroupContainerProvider]
})
export class NestedFormComponentsComponent implements FormControlContainer {

  form = new FormGroup({});

  onSubmit(e) {
    if (!this.form.valid) {
      console.log('form is INVALID!')
      if (this.form.hasError('required', ['firstName'])) {
        console.log('First name is required.');
      }
      if (this.form.hasError('required', ['lastName'])) {
        console.log('Last name is required.');
      }
    } else {
      console.log('form is VALID!');
    }
  }

  addControl(name: string, control: FormControl): void {
    this.form.addControl(name, control);
  }

  removeControl(name: string): void {
    this.form.removeControl(name);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <div>
      <label for="firstName">First name:</label>
      <input id="firstName" [formControl]="firstName" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="lastName">Last name:</label>
      <input id="lastName" [formControl]="lastName" type="text"/>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnDestroy {
  firstName: FormControl;
  lastName: FormControl;

  constructor(private _parent: FormControlContainer) {
    this.firstName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.lastName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this._parent.addControl('firstName', this.firstName);
    this._parent.addControl('lastName', this.lastName);
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._parent.removeControl('firstName');
    this._parent.removeControl('lastName');
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works when I use it just like you pasted it, but when I try to move ChildComponent to another file I get exception: "Can't resolve all parameters for ChildComponent". Can you help me with this one? I use "typescript" as a transpiler and had to add @Inject(FormControlContainer) in ChildComponent's constructor, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: @Celebes Import the provider into your child component, then add it to the providers array `providers: [formGroupContainerProvider]`

Comment: I'm trying this approach with angular 6, but it seems that: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'. [2345].` Maybe that is why I'm getting: `ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.` Question, where should I put this line then: `directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, forwardRef(() => ChildComponent)]` and what is `REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES` for?

Answer (score 1):

There is easier way to pass formGroup and formControl into lower component - using @Inputs.
**Plunker:** https://plnkr.co/edit/pd30ru?p=preview

**In FormComponent (MgForms) [main] we do:**

**in code:**

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group(formFields);
```

**in template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>

  <div class="mg-form-element" *ngFor="let element of fields">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="center-block">{{element.description?.label?.text}}:

        <div [ngSwitch]="element.type">
          <!--textfield component-->
          <div *ngSwitchCase="'textfield'"class="form-control">
            <mg-textfield
              [group]="form"
              [control]="form.controls[element.fieldId]"
              [element]="element">
            </mg-textfield>
          </div>    

          <!--numberfield component-->
          <div *ngSwitchCase="'numberfield'"class="form-control">
            <mg-numberfield
              [group]="form"
              [control]="form.controls[element.fieldId]"
              [element]="element">
            </mg-numberfield>
          </div>
        </div>

      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

**In FieldComponent (MgNumberfield) [inner] we do:**

**in code:**

```
@Input() group;
@Input() control;
@Input() element;
```

**in template:**

```
<div [formGroup]="group">
  <input
    type="text"
    [placeholder]="element?.description?.placeholder?.text"
    [value]="control?.value"
    [formControl]="control">
</div>
```

Comment: I explicitly said that I want to avoid passing everything through @Inputs, because I had to deal with much more levels of composition than just 1.