# Angular 2 form spread across components

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to create a forms component where the component provides the `<form>` and its descendants the form content, i.e. control. I am using RC4 with reactive forms. The component should be used like this:

```
<my-formwizard [form]="form">
  <input formControlName="name" type="text" />
</my-formwizard>
```

Here's a plunk showing the implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/OSzjDQD63lwoEsyqdLvw?p=preview

I run into an exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setParent' of null

Is there a way to accomplish a reactive form spread across multiple components?

---

**UPDATE**: RC5 has a clearer error message and thanks to peeskillet's input, `formControlName` can be used if the custom directive gets the `FormGroup` attached through the `formGroup` property. The updated plunk shows the form spread across two components working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1VfIH5AYjoe7dmizw6ss?p=preview

Comment: Your solution is really more of a hack, and causes _two_ `FormGroupDirective` instances to be created, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 6):

In you Plunker, I'm not sure why you have the `ngForm`

```
<my-formwizard [form]="form" ngForm="form">
```

but that shouldn't be there. I think it may even be creating a whole new form. That should be removed. Once you remove that, then you will run into another problem, saying that there is no [`ControlContainer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/ControlContainer-class.html). The `ControlContainer` is the `FormGroupDirective` (`[formGroup]`).

The problem is caused by the `formControlName`. If you look at the source for the [`FormControlName` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L108), and you look at the constructor, you will see that it requires a `ControlContainer` dependency. But not just that, it also has a `@Host`<sup>1</sup> decorator, which means it will only look for the `ControlContainer` in the host injector.

Honestly I'm not quite sure in this case which injector is used as the host injector in this case, but it appears it is not the one with the form group directive. Maybe because how you have the components set up.

A solution I found it to instead of using `formControlName`, use `[formControl]` instead, and just pass a `FormControl` instance. The [`FormControlDirective`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_directive.ts#L74) does not have this problem (where it needs a `ControlContainer`), as it is possible to be used in standalone.

So you could do this instead

```
<input [formControl]="nameCtrl" type="text" />

export class App {

  form: FormGroup;
  nameCtrl: FormControl;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.nameCtrl = new FormControl('');
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: this.nameCtrl
    });
  }
}
```

This solves your problem. Here's the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/16pqHugx7yMjyxZMTLF3?p=preview),

**See Also:**

- [How to tackle creating complex form with lots of custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38640266/2587435) for some design ideas.

---

<sub>1 - See [Host and Visibility...](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/20/host-and-visibility-in-angular-2-dependency-injection.html) for a good read on this topic</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I find creating the individual controls and maintaining a property for each to be rather tedious which is why I'm looking for a `formControlName` solution. I just tried with the current code from `forms-builds` which shows the same behavior, just a more elaborate error message: "formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class)". If I add a `formGroup` to my directive, it seems to work!

Comment: Because then the `formGroup` directive is the immediate host of the `fromControlName`, allowing the `ControlContainer` to be discovered by the `FormControlName` when it does the host lookup.