# Angular4 - No value accessor for form control

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I have a custom element :

```html
<div formControlName="surveyType">
  <div *ngFor="let type of surveyTypes"
       (click)="onSelectType(type)"
       [class.selected]="type === selectedType">
    <md-icon>{{ type.icon }}</md-icon>
    <span>{{ type.description }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I try to add the formControlName, I get an error message:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name:
>   'surveyType'

I tried to add `ngDefaultControl` without success.
It seems it's because there is no input/select... and I dont know what to do.

I would like to bind my click to this formControl in order that when someone clicks on the entire card that would push my 'type' into the formControl. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know my point is that : formControl go for form control in html but div is not a form control. I would like tu bind my surveyType with the type.id of my card div

Comment: i know i could use the old angular way and have my selectedType bind to it but i was trying to use and learn reactive form from angular 4 and dont know how to use formControl with this type of case.

Comment: Ok i it s maybe jsut that case can't be handle by a reactive form so. Thx anyway :)

Comment: I've made an answer about how to break down huge forms into sub components here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375605/2398593 but this also apply very well with just a custom control value accessor. Also check out https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form :)

Comment: I had the same issue ans solved it in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64617295/1190948

Answer (score 325, accepted):

You can use `formControlName` only on directives which implement [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor).

## Implement the interface

So, in order to do what you want, you have to create a component which implements [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor), which means **implementing the following three functions**:

- `writeValue` (tells Angular how to write value from model into view)
- `registerOnChange` (registers a handler function that is called when the view changes)
- `registerOnTouched` (registers a handler to be called when the component receives a touch event, useful for knowing if the component has been focused).

## Register a provider

Then, you have to tell Angular that this directive is a `ControlValueAccessor` (interface is not gonna cut it since it is stripped from the code when TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript). You do this by **registering a provider**.

The provider should provide [`NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) and [use an existing value](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#useexistingthe-alias-provider). You'll also need a [`forwardRef`](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#forwardref) here. Note that `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` should be a [multi provider](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html).

For example, if your custom directive is named MyControlComponent, you should add something along the following lines inside the object passed to `@Component` decorator:

```json
providers: [
  { 
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    multi: true,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyControlComponent),
  }
]
```

## Usage

Your component is ready to be used. With [template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms), `ngModel` binding will now work properly.

With [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), you can now properly use `formControlName` and the form control will behave as expected.

## Resources

- [**Custom Form Controls in Angular** by Thoughtram](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html)
- [**Angular Custom Form Controls with Reactive Forms and NgModel** by Cory Rylan](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-custom-form-controls-with-reactive-forms-and-ngmodel)

Comment: also don't forget ngDefaultControl on the concerned input.

Comment: Is it possible to include ngDefaultControl directive directly on the component, so we don't have to add it every time ?
If so how please?

Answer (score 87):

You should use `formControlName="surveyType"` on an `input` and not on a `div`

Comment: Yes sure, but i dont know how to turn my card div into something else which will be a html form control

Comment: The point of CustomValueAccessor is to add form control to ANYTHING, even a div

Comment: @SoEzPz This is a bad pattern though. You mimic Input functionality in a wrapper component, re-implementing standard HTML-methods yourself (thus basically re-inventing the wheel and making your code verbose). but in 90% of the cases you can accomplish all you want by using `<ng-content>` in a wrapper component and let the parent component that defines `formControls` simply put the <input> inside the <wrapper>

Comment: This answer gave me the notion that the structure of the HTML element in the template was incomplete.  I added a MatSelectModule import to the test configuration and this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 38):

The error means, that Angular doesn't know what to do when you put a `formControl` on a `div`.
To fix this, you have two options.

1. You put the `formControlName` on an element, that is supported by Angular out of the box. Those are: `input`, `textarea` and `select`.
2. You implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. By doing so, you're telling Angular "how to access the value of your control" (hence the name). Or in simple terms: What to do, when you put a `formControlName` on an element, that doesn't naturally have a value associated with it.

Now, implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` interface can be a bit daunting at first. Especially because there isn't much good documentation of this out there and you need to add a lot of boilerplate to your code. So let me try to break this down in some simple-to-follow steps.

### Move your form control into its own component

In order to implement the `ControlValueAccessor`, you need to create a new component (or directive). Move the code related to your form control there. Like this it will also be easily reusable. Having a control already inside a component might be the reason in the first place, why you need to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface, because otherwise you will not be able to use your custom component together with Angular forms.

### Add the boilerplate to your code

Implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` interface is quite verbose, here's the boilerplate that comes with it:

```
import {Component, OnInit, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  templateUrl: './custom-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-input.component.scss'],

  // a) copy paste this providers property (adjust the component name in the forward ref)
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
// b) Add "implements ControlValueAccessor"
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  // c) copy paste this code
  onChange: any = () => {}
  onTouch: any = () => {}
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }

  // d) copy paste this code
  writeValue(input: string) {
    // TODO
  }
```

So what are the individual parts doing?

- a) Lets Angular know during runtime that you implemented the `ControlValueAccessor` interface
- b) Makes sure you're implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` interface
- c) This is probably the most confusing part. Basically what you're doing is, you give Angular the means to override your class properties/methods `onChange` and `onTouch` with it's own implementation during runtime, such that you can then call those functions. So this point is important to understand: **You don't need to implement onChange and onTouch yourself** (other than the initial empty implementation). The only thing your doing with (c) is to let Angular attach it's own functions to your class. Why? So you can then **call** the `onChange` and `onTouch` methods provided by Angular at the appropriate time. We'll see how this works down below.
- d) We'll also see how the `writeValue` method works in the next section, when we implement it. I've put it here, so all required properties on `ControlValueAccessor` are implemented and your code still compiles.

### Implement writeValue

What `writeValue` does, is to **do something inside your custom component, when the form control is changed on the outside**. So for example, if you have named your custom form control component `app-custom-input` and you'd be using it in the parent component like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-custom-input formControlName="myFormControl"></app-custom-input>
</form>
```

then `writeValue` gets triggered whenever the parent component somehow changes the value of `myFormControl`. This could be for example during the initialization of the form (`this.form = this.formBuilder.group({myFormControl: ""});`) or on a form reset `this.form.reset();`.

What you'll typically want to do if the value of the form control changes on the outside, is to write it to a local variable which represents the form control value. For example, if your `CustomInputComponent` revolves around a text based form control, it could look like this:

```
writeValue(input: string) {
  this.input = input;
}
```

and in the html of `CustomInputComponent`:

```
<input type="text"
       [ngModel]="input">
```

You could also write it directly to the input element as described in the Angular docs.

Now you have handled what happens inside of your component when something changes outside. Now let's look at the other direction. How do you inform the outside world when something changes inside of your component?

### Calling onChange

The next step is to inform the parent component about changes inside of your `CustomInputComponent`. This is where the `onChange` and `onTouch` functions from (c) from above come into play. By calling those functions you can inform the outside about changes inside your component. In order to propagate changes of the value to the outside, you need to **call onChange with the new value as the argument**. For example, if the user types something in the `input` field in your custom component, you call `onChange` with the updated value:

```
<input type="text"
       [ngModel]="input"
       (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

If you check the implementation (c) from above again, you'll see what's happening: Angular bound it's own implementation to the `onChange` class property. That implementation expects one argument, which is the updated control value. What you're doing now is you're calling that method and thus letting Angular know about the change. Angular will now go ahead and change the form value on the outside. This is the key part in all this. **You told Angular when it should update the form control and with what value by calling `onChange`**. You've given it the means to "access the control value".

By the way: The name `onChange` is chosen by me. You could choose anything here, for example `propagateChange` or similar. However you name it though, it will be the same function that takes one argument, that is provided by Angular and that is bound to your class by the `registerOnChange` method during runtime.

### Calling onTouch

Since form controls can be "touched", you should also give Angular the means to understand when your custom form control is touched. You can do it, you guessed it, by calling the `onTouch` function. So for our example here, if you want to stay compliant with how Angular is doing it for the out-of-the-box form controls, you should call `onTouch` when the input field is blurred:

```
<input type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="input"
       (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
       (blur)="onTouch()">
```

Again, `onTouch` is a name chosen by me, but what it's actual function is provided by Angular and it takes zero arguments. Which makes sense, since you're just letting Angular know, that the form control has been touched.

### Putting it all together

So how does that look when it comes all together? It should look like this:

```
// custom-input.component.ts
import {Component, OnInit, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  templateUrl: './custom-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-input.component.scss'],

  // Step 1: copy paste this providers property
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
// Step 2: Add "implements ControlValueAccessor"
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  // Step 3: Copy paste this stuff here
  onChange: any = () => {}
  onTouch: any = () => {}
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }

  // Step 4: Define what should happen in this component, if something changes outside
  input: string;
  writeValue(input: string) {
    this.input = input;
  }

  // Step 5: Handle what should happen on the outside, if something changes on the inside
  // in this simple case, we've handled all of that in the .html
  // a) we've bound to the local variable with ngModel
  // b) we emit to the ouside by calling onChange on ngModelChange

}
```

```
// custom-input.component.html
<input type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="input"
       (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
       (blur)="onTouch()">
```

```
// parent.component.html
<app-custom-input [formControl]="inputTwo"></app-custom-input>

// OR

<form [formGroup]="form" >
  <app-custom-input formControlName="myFormControl"></app-custom-input>
</form>
```

### More Examples

- Example with Input: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-value-accessor-simple-example-tsmean
- Example with Lazy Loaded Input: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-value-accessor-lazy-input-example-tsmean
- Example with Button: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-value-accessor-button-example-tsmean

### Nested Forms

Note that Control Value Accessors are NOT the right tool for nested form groups. For nested form groups you can simply use an `@Input() subform` instead. Control Value Accessors are meant to wrap `controls`, not `groups`! See this example how to use an input for a nested form: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-forms-input-2

### Sources

- https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor
- https://www.tsmean.com/articles/angular/angular-control-value-accessor-example/

Answer (score 0):

1-Open app.module.ts

2-Add ReactiveFormModule, FormsModule to the imports section under the @NgModule decorator.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // Adding FormsModule

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule], // Adding ReactiveFormModule, FormsModule
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3-After adding the FormsModule, refresh the page as the formControlName property should work correctly.

I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

For me it was due to "multiple" attribute on select input control as Angular has different ValueAccessor for this type of control.

```
const countryControl = new FormControl();
```

And inside template use like this

```
    <select multiple name="countries" [formControl]="countryControl">
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
       {{ country.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

More details ref [Official Docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor)

Comment: _What_ was due to "multiple"? I don't see how your code solves anything, or what was the original problem. Your code shows the usual basic usage.