# formControlName to be used for div

Tags: angular

This is my reactive form object

```
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        ordSearch: ['', Validators.required],
        fromDate: ['', Validators.required],
        toDate: ['', Validators.required],
        systemId: ['', Validators.required],
        entityId: ['', Validators.required],
        pmntMethod: ['', Validators.required],
        merchantId: ['', Validators.required],
        ordStatus: ['', Validators.required],
        refNumber: ['', Validators.required],
        ordId: ['', Validators.required],
        orderDate: ['', Validators.required],
        merchId: ['', Validators.required],
        paymentMtd: ['', Validators.required],
        authAmnt: ['', Validators.required],
        accIdentifier: ['', Validators.required],
        capAmnt: ['', Validators.required],
        expDate: ['', Validators.required],
        refAmnt: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

This is my Html

```
<div class="col-md-6 orderKey">Order ID </div>
<div class="col-md-6" formControlName="ordId"></div>
```

I have to bind the ordId value to the div.
But formControlName can`t be used for div.
It is giving error ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'ordId'

Comment: Why you trying set `formControlName` to div instead of input, select etc.?

Comment: That data I`m getting from API response, which has to be bind in div.

Answer (score 3):

Form controls are meant for editing data, so angular knows how to use them with html elements like `<input>`, `<textarea>` or `<select>`—elements that are used to edit data. `<div>` is a readonly element, usually there's no point in binding form controls to it.

You can also create your own custom components (or directives) that can be bound to form controls—if they implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface. Angular has built-in `ControlValueAccessor` implementations for `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc, but not for `<div>`.

However, it looks to me that you don't want to let the user change `ordId`, you just want to show it. So it doesn't have to be a part of your form. Store it in a separate variable and bind your `<div>` to it the usual way:

```js
public orderId: number | null = null;

// After you get your response
this.orderId = response.ordId;
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 orderKey">Order ID </div>
<div class="col-md-6">{{orderId}}</div>
```

If, for some reason, you absolutely want it in your form, you can bind to the form control's value like so:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 orderKey">Order ID </div>
<div class="col-md-6">{{form.controls.ordId.value}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `formControlName` on a input instead of a div. But if you insist on using it on a div then you have to implement the `ControlValueAccessor`

Comment: can you tell me how to change my html because  data I`m getting from API response, which has to be bind in div.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659742/angular4-no-value-accessor-for-form-control?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Youar answer is right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45660571/9386929