# Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'answer'

Tags: angular6

I have the following `html`. I want to add `ace.js` editor in my code and map the value in the Editor to `answer` field of the a `form`

```
  <div class="form-group" id="answer-div">
    <div class="label-div">
      <label class="control-label"><strong>Answer</strong></label>
    </div>
    <div  id="add-more-answer-div" class="two-column-grid">
      <div id="answer-filename-div">
        <label id="filename-label" for="answer-filename">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="answer-filename">
        <button type="button" id="more-answer-button" class="unselected-button">Add More Sections</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-div" id="editor-div">
      <div id="editor" class="form-control" formControlName="answer" [ngClass]="validateField('answer')">Remove this and enter code here</div>
      <app-show-errors [control]="practiceQuestionForm.controls.answer"></app-show-errors>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The corresponding `form` is

```
    this.practiceQuestionForm = this.fb.group({
...
      answer:[null,Validators.required],
....
    })
```

When I run the code,  I get the error `Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'answer'` corresponding to `html` code `<div id="editor" class="form-control" formControlName="answer" [ngClass]="validateField('answer')">Remove this and enter code here</div>`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can a div be a form control? I don't think so.

Comment: maybe you are right. checking this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988119/formcontrolname-to-be-used-for-div

Comment: I don't get the error anymore if I put a `textarea` within `div` but I still have to check if this will work well w.r.t mapping the `textarea` with `form's` field `<div id="editor"> <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="answer" [ngClass]="validateField('answer')">Remove this and enter code here</textarea></div>`

Comment: textarea is kind of like an input field so you can use reactive forms for that maybe.