# Angular FormArray: Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I trying to build an Angular Reactive form where an account can add many students.

The form seems to work. When you hit Add Student it creates a new student but you check the console it says

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'studentsArray -> 1 ->
>   firstName

and so on for each control in the array.

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="accountForm">
<div>
    <input formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First name">
</div>
<div>
    <input formControlName="lastName" placeholder="Last name">
</div>
<div>
    <input formControlName="phone" placeholder="Phone">
</div>
<div>
    <input formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<button (click)="addStudent()" *ngIf="!showStudentForm">Add Student</button>
<div formArrayName="studentsArray">
    <div *ngFor="let student of studentsArray.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <input formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
        <input formControlName="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input formControlName="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth">
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
 @Input() account: Account;
  accountForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

   createForm() {
    this.accountForm = this.fb.group({
      'firstName': '',
      'lastName': '',
      'email': '',
      'phone': '',
      'studentsArray': this.fb.array([])
    });
   }

   ngOnChanges() {
    this.rebuildForm();
  }

  rebuildForm() {
    this.accountForm.reset({
      firstName: this.account.firstName,
      lastName: this.account.lastName,
      email: this.account.email,
      phone: this.account.phone
    });
    this.setStudents(this.account.students);
  }

  get studentsArray(): FormArray {
    return this.accountForm.get('studentsArray') as FormArray;
  }

  setStudents(students: Student[]) {
    const studentFGs = students.map(student => this.fb.group(student));
    const studentFormArray = this.fb.array(studentFGs);
    this.accountForm.setControl('studentsArray', studentFormArray);
  }

  addStudent() {
    this.studentsArray.push(this.fb.group(new Student()));
  }
}

export class Account {
  public firstName: '';
  public lastName: '';
  public email: '';
  public phone: '';
  public students: Student[];
}

export class Student {
  firstName: '';
  lastName: '';
  dob: '';
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqvv3a

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Method 1:
[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssegtf;)
In your Component:

```
  addStudent() {
    this.studentsArray.push(this.fb.group({
      firstName:new FormControl (""),
      lastName: new FormControl (""),
      dob: new FormControl ("")
    }))
  }
```

Method 2:
[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-llkzlk)
In your component:

```
import { Student } from './student.model'

 addStudent() {
    this.studentsArray.push(this.fb.group(new Student()));
  }
```

Create Student Model:
file name: student.model.ts

file contents:

```
export class Student{
  constructor(
    public firstName:string,
    public lastName:string,
    public dob:string
  ){}
}
```

For either Method 1 or 2:

In your Html:

```
<div formArrayName="studentsArray" ">
    <div *ngFor="let student of studentsArray.controls; let i = index" formGroupName="{{i}}">
        <input formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
        <input formControlName="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input formControlName="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can display the value of the form for easy testing like this:

```
{{accountForm.value | json}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Farasi78. That works! I was hoping to pass it a model instead of entering all the controls. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you want to do it that way, create Student as a model and import it - I tried it with the definition inline and it didn't seem to work.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-llkzlk. Check that out.

Comment: @Ty did you manage to make it work?  If so, and this answer was correct please indicate as appropriate.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!  The second method allows you to do it with the model rather than having to specify each control individually.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using Angular 10 and after many tries and research, I finally found the error, I was using `[formControlName]` notation in the `<input>` element, and as soon as I removed the square brackets for simply `formControlName` it finally works, not sure why but I hope it could help

Comment: Yeah... https://stackoverflow.com/a/45659791/5468463