# Get values in formArray Angular: Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, formarray

I want to get the values on my simple Form inside a formArray but it's giving me errors. I have tried other solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51364862/angular-formarray-cannot-find-control-with-path) but it's not working.

Here's my sample code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-array-values

```
    ----- HTML
<div class="form-group" formArrayName="optionGroup">
   <div *ngFor="let data of menuOptions; let i = index">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i" class=" " id="{{i}}">
                      <input
                        formControlName="optionsQty"
                        class="form-input qty qty{{i}}"
                        type="number"
                        id="qty{{i}}"
                        min="1"
                        [(ngModel)]="defaultOptionQtyTotal"
                      />
        
                      <input
                        formControlName="optionsName"
                        class="form-input"
                        type="text"
                        readonly
                        value=" {{data.name}} {{i}}"
                        id="optName{{i}}"
                      />
        
                      $<input
                        formControlName="optionsCost"
                        class="form-input"
                        type="text"
                        readonly
                        value=" {{data.cost}}"
                        id="optName{{i}}"
                      />
                    </div>
            </div>
```

here's the .TS

```
----- TS
 constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.builder.group({
      qtyTotal: this.builder.control("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.min(1)
      ]),

      optionGroup: this.builder.array([]);
     });
  } //end constructor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the form array in your class.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.initFormArray();
}

initFormArray() {
    this.menuOptions.forEach(x => {
      (<FormArray>this.form.get("optionGroup")).push(
        this.builder.group({
          optionsQty: [null],
          optionsName: [x.name],
          optionsCost: [x.cost]
        })
      );
    });
  }
```

You got an issue because you try to access the empty form array in HTML.

updated [solution.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-array-values-dumwrd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)