# How to create component that can support ngModel and ngControl directives

Tags: angular, dart

To get access to NgControl in my component I create constructor:

```
NgControl _cd;
MyDateEditComponent(@Self() @Optional() this._cd);
```

I want use my component like this:

```
<my-date-edit [(ngModel)]="date" ngControl="date">
```

or

```
<my-date-edit [(date)]="date" ngControl="date">
```

Now I have error:

*Assertion failed: "No value accessor for (date) or you may be missing formDirectives in your directives list."*

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using a ngModel on a custom component use the `ControlValueAccessor`

```
export class YourComponent implements ControlValueAccessor { 
    // need to imlement following methods
    onChange = (val: Date) => { };
    onTouched = () => { };

    writeValue(val: Date) {
        // your ngModel value comes under here
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (val: Date) => void) {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added implementation of `ControlValueAccessor<String>`, but error still there. I stub every method with print('stub'). There is not output in console. Only error.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Assertion failed: "No value accessor for (date) or you may be missing formDirectives in your directives list."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659742/angular4-no-value-accessor-for-form-control?answertab=active#tab-top