# How to validate textbox using reactive form validation

Tags: angular5, angular6, angular7

I have created custom text component for textbox and i am trying to validate by reactive form validation but not working.

Getting Error:

ERROR
Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll want to add a formGroup
directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

Anyone can help to resolve this issue?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-9pu6hq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

app.component.html:

```
<app-textbox formControlName="password"></app-textbox>
```

app.component.ts:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `app-textbox` in between a `form` element that is assigned to the form group:

```
   <form [group]="registerForm">
      <app-textbox formControlName="password"></app-textbox>
   </form>
```

Comment: How it is possible? Bcoz already i have used app-textbox inside the form..Can you check app.component?

Comment: ah sorry, didn't see that. 
I guess this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45660571/10713841

You cant just use your own components as a form control.

Comment: I have checked but not working..Can you check this code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eac5pk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html