# How to use formGroupName inside child components

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

How do i use formGroupName inside child components?
for example:

i have **ParentFormComponent**

```
    parentForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: Http) { }
    ngOnInit() {


 this.parentForm = this.fb.group({
        _general: this.fb.group ({
           ProjectName:''
       })
  })
 }
```

In the html:

```
  <form [formGroup]="parentForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
     <div formGroupName="_general">
        <mat-form-field>
             <input matInput placeholder="Project name" 
             formControlName="ProjectName">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div> 
  </form>
```

it's working great but when i want to use child component it's not working:

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
          <app-child [parentForm]='parentForm'></app-child>
      </form>
```

when i insert it to the child component:

```
<div formGroupName="_general">
            <mat-form-field>
                 <input matInput placeholder="Project name" 
                 formControlName="ProjectName">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

and in the ts file

```
 @Input() parentForm:FormGroup;
```

i"m getting error:
formGroupName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
      directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

Comment: Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63046643/5629298) it might help you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Instead of Using input property binding Use FormGroupDirective

**FormGroupDirective**

> This directive accepts an existing FormGroup instance. It will then
>   use this FormGroup instance to match any child FormControl, FormGroup,
>   and FormArray instances to child FormControlName, FormGroupName, and
>   FormArrayName directives.

Use Viewproviders to provide controlContainer, Inject FormGroupDirective in your child component to get the parentform instance

**app.parent.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <app-child></app-child>
</form>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ControlContainer, FormGroupDirective, Validators, FormBuilder, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  childForm;
  constructor(private parentF: FormGroupDirective) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.childForm = this.parentF.form;
    this.childForm.addControl('_general', new FormGroup({
      ProjectName: new FormControl('')
    }))

  }
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<div formGroupName="_general">
     <mat-form-field>
                 <input matInput placeholder="Project name" 
                 formControlName="ProjectName"> 
      <mat-form-field>  
 </div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezqupz

Comment: Is there a way to add mutiple components with the same formGroupName ?

Comment: @billyjov what do you mean by multiple components?

Comment: i'm trying something like this in the CLI https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-magic

Comment: It's works fine on stackblitz but not inside my app

Comment: Works thanks... i forgetted to use new FormGroup to build the parent form

Comment: why not just pass the formgroup as an input?
`<app-child 
[myFormGroup]="myForm.get('myFormGroup')">`
or
`<app-child [myFormControl]="myForm.get('myFormControl')">`

Comment: This works when the field is directly inside the form group defined by `[formGroup]` but `formGroupName` doesn't work for me. I'd have to use `[formGroup]="parentForm.get('_general')"` in this example. The example on stackblitz doesn't seem to use nested form groups. Is there a way to get formGroupName to work too?

Comment: Do You want to get nested form group name inside custom component? @ClaudeMartin

Comment: @Chellappanவ I just want to use `formGroupName="foo"` like I could when not using a custom component. I don't know why it doesn't work on my project. I get `Cannot find control with name: 'xxx'`. It works when I use `[formGroup]="root.get('foo')"` instead. Is there another directive I have to declare for it to work?

Comment: If it possible can you please create  stackblitz?

Comment: @Chellappanவ I forked yours: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynjdlm
This doesn't work because I use `formGroupName`. See `app.component.html` to see how `[formGroup]` would work, but `formGroupName` doesn't.

Comment: You could do something like this as a workaround: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssryuc.

Comment: If you are looking for more generic check this blog:https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-nested-reactive-forms-using-cvas-b394ba2e5d0d

Comment: So I ended up implementing `ControlValueAccessor`. Then it works.

Comment: How do you unit test components using this approach? How do you avoid `No provider for FormGroupDirective`? I've tried a number of approaches but none have worked.

Comment: @Splaktar Can you create sample repo or something?

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to pass the formGroup to the child component, just provide a `ControlContainer` and use formGroupName like this:

parent html:

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <app-child></app-child>
</form>
```

parent ts:

```
 this.parentForm = this.fb.group({
        _general: this.fb.group ({
           ProjectName:''
       })
  })
```

child html:

```
<div formGroupName="_general">
     <mat-form-field>
                 <input matInput placeholder="Project name" 
                 formControlName="ProjectName"> 
      <mat-form-field>  
 </div>
```

child ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ControlContainer, FormGroupDirective, Validators, FormBuilder, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

That way, your entire form configuration is in the parent component without splitting it into the childrens .ts, they only act as views.